# Installation And Unistallation Of Tomcat

Tags: tomcat, eclipse

I just installed the tomcat 10.0.12 using below command

```
$ mkdir /opt/tomcat
```

```
$ cd /opt/tomcat
```

```
sudo wget https://dlcdn.apache.org/tomcat/tomcat-10/v10.0.12/bin/apache-tomcat-10.0.12.tar.gz
```

```
$ tar xvzf apache-tomcat-8.5.65.tar.gz
```

```
$ nano ~/.bashrc
and set the environment variabels in it which are
export JAVA_HOME=/usr/lib/jvm/jdk-17
export CATALINA_HOME=/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-10.0.12
saved the changes
```

```
$ . ~/.bashrc
```

```
$ $CATALINA_HOME/bin/startup.sh
```

then i runned http://127.0.0.1:8080 in browser it worked perfectly fine for me
but when i checked that application for which i installed the tomcat 10.0.12 it said for now its not supported to use tomcat i have to install tomcat 10.0.10 so i unistalled tomcat using below command

```
sudo rm -rf /opt/tomcat
```

and installed tomcat 10.0.10 by making few changes in above code but when i runned http://127.0.0.1:8080 again the page shown me this
[image: error]
instead of showing me this
[image: the image which should be shown]
please ignore 8.5.05 cause i downloaded this image from another website which was providing tutorial to insatll tomcat on linux
i think tomcat didn't uninstall completely and still running what should i do please tell me

Comment: Hi, and what is saying your $CATALINA_HOME/logs/catalina.log ?

Comment: There are breaking changes between Servlet 4.0 (Tomcat 9.0) and Servlet 5.0 (Tomcat 10.0): the API migrated from the `javax` to the `jakarta` namespace. Check [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/66806582/11748454) for an overview of the problem.